# Pretty print XML with Swift 3

Tags: xml, swift, swift3, pretty-print

With *Swift 2.2* I used to prettify XML like that:

```
let detxTag = NSXMLElement(name: "detx")
let xml = NSXMLDocument(rootElement: detxTag)

// ...

let data = xml.XMLDataWithOptions(NSXMLNodePrettyPrint | NSXMLNodeCompactEmptyElement)
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible with *Swift 3* anymore with this code (automatically converted by *Xcode 8*):

```
let detxTag = XMLElement(name: "detx")
let xml = XMLDocument(rootElement: detxTag)

// ...

let data = xml.xmlData(withOptions: NSXMLNodePrettyPrint)
```

It produces the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'NSXMLNodePrettyPrint'
```

It seems that in/out options have changed but it is not very clear how to use it: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/xmldocument/input_and_output_options

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`xmlData(withOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/xmldocument/1412424-xmldata) accepts [`XMLNode.Options`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/xmlnode.options), but they must be
converted to an `Int`:

```
let data = xml.xmlData(withOptions: Int(XMLNode.Options.nodePrettyPrint.rawValue))
```

or for multiple options:

```
let options: XMLNode.Options = [.nodePrettyPrint, .nodeCompactEmptyElement]
let data = xml.xmlData(withOptions: Int(options.rawValue))
```

As of **Swift 4,** `xmlData(withOptions:)` takes a `XMLNode.Options`
argument, so this simplifies to

```
let data = xml.xmlData(options: .nodePrettyPrint)
```

for a single option, or

```
let data = xml.xmlData(options: [.nodePrettyPrint, .nodeCompactEmptyElement])
```

for multiple options.

Comment: This is kind of weird: I thought swift 3 was bringing more consistency...

Comment: @MartinDelille: Sure, it would be nice if the `Int(options.rawValue)` conversion wasn't necessary, but I cannot change it. You can file a bug report at Apple if it is important for you.

Comment: No it is not that important: I don't blame your answer don't worry ;-)

Comment: Filling radar is boring since it is totally opaque.

Comment: Thanks, that was a really stinky one. Still some work left in the API conversions for Swift ;-)

Comment: @patrickS:  You are right (actually already since Swift 4/Xcode 9), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Swift 4.2 :

```
if let xml = try? XMLElement.init(xmlString:"<A><b>test</b><c>test</c></A>") {
   let data = xmlDoc.xmlData(options:.nodePrettyPrint)
   let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
   print(str)
}

//Output:
<A>
   <b>test</b>
   <c>test</c>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be:

```
func prettyFormat(xmlString:String) -> String? {
  do {
    let xml = try XMLDocument.init(xmlString: xmlString)
    let data = xml.xmlData(options: .nodePrettyPrint)
    let str:String? = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    return str
  }
  catch {
    print (error.localizedDescription)
  }
  return nil
}
```

Usage:

```
var str = "Hello, XML Pretty Format playground"
let testStr:String? = "<A><b>test</b>  <c>test</c><d>\(str)</d></A>  "


let aStr = prettyFormat(xmlString: "<A><b>test</b>  <c>test</c><d>\(str)</d></A>  ")
print (aStr ?? "?")

let bStr = prettyFormat(xmlString:testStr!)
print (bStr ?? "?")
```

XMLElement.init is not working ...
Please improve ..